# C Preprocessor - Add Elements to Struct at Compile Time

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to think of a way to add elements to a struct at compile time, but by defining this in another file.  For example:

defA.h:

```
typedef struct A {
    int element1;
    int element2;
} A;
```

otherfile.c:

```
#include "defA.h"

typedef struct B {
    int element1;
} B;

ADD_ELEMENT_TO(A, B, element3)
```

Would result in:

```
struct A {
    int element1;
    int element2;
    B element3;
};
```

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this or something similar? I want to be able to control this by choosing to compile `otherfile.c` or not with the rest of the build.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is not unusual to want the contents of some structures to depend on conditional compilation, but most often it is simply done with `#if` statements that simply include the desired members or not. Or one might define a macro that conditional expands to declarations of the desired members or to an empty string and then use that macro in the structure declaration. Are things like that sufficient for you? If not, why do you want to try this more complicated method; what goal would it accomplish for you?

Comment: I understand that I can conditionally add `element3` to the struct with `#if`, however I'm looking for a more elegant way to place it there.  Say I deliver source code to my customer, but they only pay for certain features.  If they haven't paid for the code in `otherfile.c`, I either have to supply them with it anyway, or sanitise my code somehow.  If the definitions relating to `otherfile.c` were only added to the structure by its inclusion in the build, then the issue would be avoided.  I know it would cause issues with debugging, etc. but I'm interested to see what SO comes up with.

Comment: The type of `struct A` is complete and final when the `}` of the definition is encountered while processing `defA.h`.  It cannot be modified after that.  You _could_ (but shouldn't) create a new type at a function scope (or a scope inside a function), but it wouldn't be modifying the existing `struct A`; it would merely be hiding (shadowing) the other declaration.  You would have to defer the definition of `struct A` until after the definition of `struct B` if you wish to embed a `B` inside `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution using C preprocessor features is going to make a mess where the structure is declared. For example:

Main source/header:

```
#include "SpecialSauce.h"
…
typedef struct A {
    int element1;
    int element2;
    SpecialStuff
} A;
```

If the customer just bought the base software, SpecialSauce.h contains:

```
#define SpecialStuff
```

If the customer pays for extra, SpecialSauce.h contains:

```
#define SpecialStuff int element3;
```

And, of course, one will need code that does or does not use `element3` according to which version of the software is present.

All of this can be controlled by preprocessor directives, and it can often be kept not too messy by giving it proper care. But commercial pressures often preclude that and result in software growing messier and in maintenance being neglected. So these sort of kludges will grow ugly and costly.

Another alternative is to keep master source files and use them to generate source files with selected options. Only the generated source files would be provided to customers, and they would not have ugly preprocessor conditions. However, this creates a need for software to process the master source files, which itself must be maintained, and the master source files still have to have some sort of conditions, which you might be able to keep nice since they are under your control, but, again, real-world software has a tendency to grow messy.